# Memory efficient 2D bit storage in Ruby (100M items)

Tags: ruby, optimization, data-structures, boolean, bit

I want to use a large data structure to represent a bit (0 or 1) or boolean (true/false) in Ruby.

In below example code, I am using a 2D array of size 10^4 * 10^4, to store a boolean data.

```
require 'get_process_mem'

num = 10000
twod =  Array.new(num) { Array.new(num, false)}
for i in 0..num-1 do
  for j in 0..num-1 do
    twod[i][j] = i>j
  end
end

mem = GetProcessMem.new
puts mem.inspect
```

The output shows that it uses ~778 MB.

```
#<GetProcessMem:0x00000078 @mb=777.93359375 @gb=0.7597007751464844 @kb=796604.0 @bytes=0.815722496e9>
```

I just tried changing the data type to integer in the code, and memory usage reports the same value.

Updated code:

```
require 'get_process_mem'

num = 10000
twod =  Array.new(num) { Array.new(num, 500)}
for i in 0..num-1 do
  for j in 0..num-1 do
    twod[i][j] = 1000+i+j
  end
end

mem = GetProcessMem.new
puts mem.inspect
```

Output:

```
#<GetProcessMem:0x00000078 @mb=777.6015625 @gb=0.7593765258789062 @kb=796264.0 @bytes=0.815374336e9>
```

I was expecting that boolean array would use less memory than integer array, which does not seem to be the case!
Is there any other optimized way to store bit or boolean values?

Comment: A boolean in Ruby isn't just a single bit, it's a full-fledged object. The size comes from the array structure itself. It doesn't really matter if you store booleans, nils, integers (up to a certain size) or floats – all of those are heavily optimized.

Comment: You could use a binary encoded string of size 12,500,000. Each character is 8 bits which gives 12,500,00 × 8 = 100,000,000. Fetching and storing bits requires some effort / math, but it would be quite memory efficient: only 12 MB. Or maybe something in-between like a 10,000 element array of 1,250-character strings.

Comment: Take a look at the [`bitarray`](https://github.com/peterc/bitarray) gem. Note that it uses `0` and `1`, not `false` and `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a byte array in a FFI:Buffer to get good size/performance
https://rubydoc.info/github/ffi/ffi/FFI/Buffer
and do bit operations on each byte:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'get_process_mem'
require 'ffi'
BIT_OP = {
  get: 1,
  set: 2,
  clear: 3,
}
class BitStore
  attr_accessor :buf, :size
  def initialize(shape) # ex [10000,10000] [10,20,30], etc
    @shp = shape
    @size = 1;
    shape.each do | sz |
      @size *= sz
    end
    @size = max(next8(@size)/8, 8) + 1 # min size needed
    clear = true
    @buf = FFI::Buffer.new(@size,1,clear)
  end
  def max(x,y)
    x > y ? x : y
  end
  def next8(val)
    val % 8 == 0 ? val+8 : ((val / 8).to_i + 1)*8
  end
  def write_buf_to_file(fname)
    fout = File.open(fname, "wb")
    fout.write(@buf.get_bytes(0,@size))
    fout.close
  end
  def check_position(coord_arr)
    if coord_arr.size != @shp.size
      raise "coord_arr size != shape size"
    end
    coord_arr.each_with_index do | coord, i |
      if coord_arr[i] > @shp[i]-1
        raise "coord index out of bounds "
      end
    end
  end
  def get_position(coord_arr)
    position = coord_arr[0]
    (1..coord_arr.size-1).each do | i |
      position += coord_arr[i] * @shp.reverse[i]
    end
    return position
  end
  def bit_op(coord_arr, op)
    check_position(coord_arr)
    position = get_position(coord_arr)
    offset = (position / 8).to_i
    bit_pos = (position % 8)
    bit_val = 1 << bit_pos
    val = @buf.get_string(offset, 1)
    numeric_value = val == "" ? 0 : val.unpack("C")[0]
    case op
    when BIT_OP[:get]
      numeric_value = numeric_value & bit_val
      return numeric_value > 0 ? "set" : "clear"
    when BIT_OP[:set]
      numeric_value = numeric_value | bit_val
    when BIT_OP[:clear]
      numeric_value = numeric_value & (bit_val ^ 0xff)
    end
    @buf.put_string(offset,[numeric_value].pack("C"))
    return ""
  end
end
def main
  begin
    rows = 10000
    cols = 10000
    b = BitStore.new([rows,cols])
    
    puts "setting [3,0]"
    b.bit_op([3,0],BIT_OP[:set])
    is_set = b.bit_op([3,0],BIT_OP[:get])
    puts is_set

    puts "setting [8000,8000]"
    b.bit_op([8000,8000],BIT_OP[:set])
    is_set = b.bit_op([8000,8000],BIT_OP[:get])
    puts is_set

    puts "clearing [8000,8000]"
    b.bit_op([8000,8000],BIT_OP[:clear])
    is_set = b.bit_op([8000,8000],BIT_OP[:get])
    puts is_set

    mem = GetProcessMem.new
    puts mem.inspect
  rescue NoMemoryError => e
    puts "NoMemoryError"
    p e
    p e.backtrace.inspect
  end
end
main
```

Memory use is 26MB:

```
user1@debian10 /home/user1/rubynew > ./pack_testb.rb 
setting [3,0]
set
setting [8000,8000]
set
clearing [8000,8000]
clear
#<GetProcessMem:0x000000a0 @mb=26.6953125 @gb=0.02606964111328125 @kb=27336.0 @bytes=0.27992064e8>
```

The file structure on disk:

```
b = BitStore.new([7,6])
puts "setting [3,0]"
b.bit_op([3,0],BIT_OP[:set])
is_set = b.bit_op([3,0],BIT_OP[:get])
puts is_set
b.write_buf_to_file("/tmp/the_buf.bin")
system("xxd /tmp/the_buf.bin")

puts "setting [6,5]"
b.bit_op([6,5],BIT_OP[:set])
is_set = b.bit_op([6,5],BIT_OP[:get])
puts is_set
b.write_buf_to_file("/tmp/the_buf.bin")
system("xxd /tmp/the_buf.bin")

setting [3,0]
00000000: 0800 0000 0000 0000 00
setting [6,5]
00000000: 0000 0000 0002 0000 00
```